# Static map successfully adds elements but is still empty

Tags: c++

I am building my static `unordered_map` through a static function. And key value pairs are added successfully in that function. But when I try to retrieve a value from the map by interacting directly with the static map it doesn't contain that value?

Whats going wrong and how can I fix it?

In Status.h:

```
typedef int STATE;
typedef std::string tstring;

class Status
{
public:

    static Status registerState(const tstring &stateMsg);
    explicit Status(const STATE &state);
    const STATE state;

    static std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> states;
    static STATE nextState;
};
```

In Status.cpp:

```
// Class Property Implementation //
STATE Status::nextState;
std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> Status::states;

// Static Function Implementation //
Status Status::registerState(const tstring &stateMsg)
{
    // Initialise here to avoid the "static initialisation order fiasco"
    static STATE nextState = 50000;
    static std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> states;

    // absence of the above causes runtime error upon emplacing the value
    // Error: Unhandled exception at 0x0125D326 in TestCBA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

    int nextStateTmp = nextState + 1;
    auto res = states.emplace(std::make_pair(nextStateTmp, stateMsg));
    printf("Storing: %d, %s, Res: %d\n", states.size(), stateMsg.c_str(), res.second);
    printf("Retrieval: [%d,%s]\n", nextStateTmp, states[nextStateTmp].c_str());

    return (res.second) ? Status(++nextState) : Status(res.first->first);
}

// Function Implementation //
Status::Status(const STATE &state) : state(state)
{

}
```

In main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Status s1 = Status::registerState("abc");

    printf("Exists: %d\n", Status::states.find(s1.state) != Status::states.end());
    printf("Lookup: %s\n", Status::states[s1.state].c_str());
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Storing: 1, abc, Res: 1
>   Retrieval: [50001,abc]
>   Exists: 0
>   Lookup: Press

Comment: Remove the line `static std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> states;` and use the static map in the class.

Comment: `// Initialise here to avoid the "static initialisation order fiasco"` - what did you mean?

Answer (score 4):

You have two `states`variables, inside the class and inside the registerState function.

In the first line of main you call the function to store a new element, which is inserted in the object inside the function. Then, this function shows the result: `Storing: 1`. Then, in the second part of main, you use the static object of the class, which is empty.

UPDATE:

The variable of the class is initialised by the constructor, when defined in the file (just below your class definition). Think in this variable as a global variable, but inside the class scope.

The second one is also as a global variable, but only known inside the function. The first is initialized in the constructor, as a global variable. The second is initialized in the first call to the funcion.

Probably you are confused because of the order of initialization problem. In your case, this problem is not important, because this problem only occurs if the initialization order of global variables affects the final result. I guess you have found some solutions related to the inclusion of objects inside functions (as static objects) to ensure that the order is appropriate. In  this solution, the static objects inside the class would desspear.

Comment: I thought that `static std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> states;` inside `Status::registerState()` would initialise the static variable - or thats what I was told in another question

Comment: @Merl `static std::unordered_map<STATE, tstring> states;` creates a completely new map inside the `Status::registerState()` function. It just happens to have the same name as the static class member.